# Exported typescript class function logs "this" as undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript

I currently have a typescript class that sets class values in a constructor. I then reference these values using "this" in a class method. The .ts file compiles fine without warnings. However, when I import the compiled .js file in another project, if I call the class method I get an error that this is undefined.

I have a few tests written for the file in typescript, and they all work fine.

Here's a simplified example.

```
# class .ts file

export class MyClass {
  public myValue: number;

  constructor(val: number) {
     this.myValue = val;
  }

  logValue() {
     console.log(this);

     console.log(this.myValue);
  }
}


# regular js project importing built .js file

import { MyClass } from 'myProject'

const x = new MyClass(5);

x.logValue(); // error, cannot read property myValue of undefined, first console.log logs 'undefined';
```

here's my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",

        // useTypeInferenceAsMuchAsPossible
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./lib",
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "es5",

        "lib": [
            "es7",
            "es2015.symbol",
            "es2015.symbol.wellknown"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us your compiled JS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code actually *does not error*:

```
const x = new MyClass(5);
x.logValue();
```

However this *will* error:

```
const x = new MyClass(5);
const logValue = x.logValue;
logValue(); // Error
```

It is simply because of how `this` works.

## Fix

You can use an [arrow function](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html). Change:

```
logValue() {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(this.myValue);
}
```

To :

```
logValue = () => {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(this.myValue);
}
```